# CSS fix for firefox: Box shadow property

Tags: css, firefox

This is my CSS code:

```
.thzPartsHeader, .thzPartsContainer {
    border:1px solid #0080ff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #0080ff, 0 0 20px #292929 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 6px #0080ff, 0 0 20px #292929 inset;
    box-shadow:0 0 6px #0080ff, 0 0 20px #292929 inset;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    margin:auto;

    font-family:georgia;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

This is HTML code:

```
<fieldset class="thzPartsContainer">
    <legend class="thzPartsHeader"><b>Code Will Appear Below</b></legend>
    <textarea class="textArea" id="txtarea" name="codearea"></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

This is how it appears in Google Chrome (This is exactly what I want):

[image: https://googledrive.com/host/0BxoUWoRI6JTIRi11REZfWEtrcU0/chromepreview.jpg]

But this is how it appears in Firefox (no reputation to post images :o ):
[image: https://googledrive.com/host/0BxoUWoRI6JTIRi11REZfWEtrcU0/firefoxpreview.jpg]
<sub>(source: [googledrive.com](https://googledrive.com/host/0BxoUWoRI6JTIRi11REZfWEtrcU0/firefoxpreview.jpg))</sub>

It appears as if the shadows are displaced and `margin:auto` property is not working in firefox. What is the fix for both of them? please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2ndc/

Comment: Legends are difficult to render consistently. You'll probably wnat to use a standard div instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702422/i-want-to-have-some-cross-browser-consistency-on-my-fieldsets-do-you-know-how-c and http://stackoverflow.com and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937508/why-does-firefox-4-absolutely-position-fieldset-legends-differently-than-other-b/questions/3973456/default-css-values-for-a-fieldset-legend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shadow part of your question is a duplicate of

[Box shadow CSS with a <fieldset>. Firefox vs Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289273/box-shadow-css-with-a-fieldset-firefox-vs-chrome)

Not the best solution as you will have to have a fixed height and width for the `<legend>` but adding this could work

```
.thzPartsHeader{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
.thzPartsContainer{
  padding-top: 9px;
  position: relative;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FBca7/2/